# How can i loop jquery code or restart it?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

How can I loop this code so that it runs after the script finishes running. Then he repeats it all over again.

i wanna make repat this code infinity times.

This is jquery 3.5.1

```
// Title
    var title1 = document.getElementById("slide-text-title-id");
    var title2 = document.getElementById("slide-text-title-id-2");
    var title3 = document.getElementById("slide-text-title-id-3");

        $(document).ready(function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $(title1).css("opacity", "1");
                $(title1).css("transition", "0.5s");
            }, 500);
            setTimeout(function () {
                $(title1).css("opacity", "0");
            }, 6000);
            setTimeout(function () {
                $(title1).css("opacity", "1");
            }, 20000);
        });

        $(document).ready(function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $(title2).css("opacity", "1");
                $(title2).css("transition", "0.5s");
            }, 9000);
            setTimeout(function () {
                $(title2).css("opacity", "0");
            }, 13500);
            setTimeout(function () {
                $(title2).css("opacity", "1");
            }, 20000);
        });

        $(document).ready(function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $(title3).css("opacity", "1");
                $(title3).css("transition", "0.5s");
            }, 16000);
            setTimeout(function () {
                $(title3).css("opacity", "0");
            }, 21000);
            setTimeout(function () {
                $(title3).css("opacity", "1");
            }, 26500);
        });
```

Comment: you can use `while(true)`. but why do you want to run infinite times ? It would causes sluggish

Comment: @KopiBryant I wanna make loop,but when all the code runs out. Then a repat that

Comment: Use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`? OR wrap the code inside each document.ready with a `setInterval` and set the duration to max of each value of setTimeotu interval for each block

Comment: @adiga I want all this code to finish first and then to repeat it all over again.

Comment: `$(document).ready(function () { setInterval(function() { // all setTimeout here }), 20000) })` <- use the max value in setTimeout for each block

Answer (score 0):

The principle:

```
// the collection:
const elements = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

// the stepper function (also called walker or iterator)
function stepper(index) {
  // the current item is elements[index];
  // do something (anything) with current item:

  console.log({
    index,
    [`currentItem (elements[${index}])`]: elements[index]
  });

  // after a while (3000ms), call this function again, with next index:
  // when current item is last, we call with `0`, so it loops:

  setTimeout(function() {
    stepper(index + 1 < elements.length ? index + 1 : 0);
    /* the above line is shorthand for:
       if (index + 1 < elements.length) {
         stepper(index + 1);
       } else {
         stepper(0);
       }
     */
  } , 3000);
}

// start the loop: 
stepper(0);
```

Now, let's try it with some elements. Arguably, the easiest way to handle this is to toggle the class `active` on a collection of slides. Using CSS, we apply styles to the active element. In order to be able to control the direction of the animation, I'm also adding a `leaving` class to the currently active slide, which I'm removing in the next iteration.

The rest are details. As a rule of thumb, details are important in web development.

```js
const elements = [1, 2, 3];

function stepper(index) {
  // remove class leaving from all slides
  $('.slider .leaving').removeClass('leaving');

  // add class leaving to the previously active item and remove class active
  $('.slider .active').addClass('leaving').removeClass('active');

  // add class active to current item
  $('.slider > div').eq(index).addClass('active');

  setTimeout(() => stepper(index < elements.length - 1 ? index + 1 : 0), 2100);
}

// start the infinite loop:

stepper(0);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.slider {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slider > div {
  font-size: 7rem;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translateX(100%);
  background-color: #ccc;
  color: white;
}
.slider .leaving {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  transition: transform .42s cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1);
}
.slider .active {
  position: relative;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: transform .42s cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider">
  <div>Slide 1</div>
  <div>Slide 2</div>
  <div>Slide 3</div>
</div>
```

---

Note: I tried to present the principle and then a minimal implementation. In the wild, code gets more complex and more verbose. Looking at your current attempt, I'd advise you to go through the basics first.

Probably the fastest way to learn is by watching tutorials accompanied by playing with the code presented there. Don't be afraid to change code. Change everything, little by little and see where it breaks.

At every single line you can use `console.log({ stuff })` to see what's in `stuff` at that exact line.
Break code. The sooner you understand why it broke, the sooner you'll know that bit, too!

Answer (score -2):

with `setInterval`

```
var interval = setInterval(function ()
{
  // Title
  var title1 = document.getElementById("slide-text-title-id");
  var title2 = document.getElementById("slide-text-title-id-2");
  var title3 = document.getElementById("slide-text-title-id-3");

  $(document).ready(function () {
      setTimeout(function () {
          $(title1).css("opacity", "1");
          $(title1).css("transition", "0.5s");
      }, 500);
      setTimeout(function () {
          $(title1).css("opacity", "0");
      }, 6000);
      setTimeout(function () {
          $(title1).css("opacity", "1");
      }, 20000);
  });

  $(document).ready(function () {
      setTimeout(function () {
          $(title2).css("opacity", "1");
          $(title2).css("transition", "0.5s");
      }, 9000);
      setTimeout(function () {
          $(title2).css("opacity", "0");
      }, 13500);
      setTimeout(function () {
          $(title2).css("opacity", "1");
      }, 20000);
  });

  $(document).ready(function () {
      setTimeout(function () {
          $(title3).css("opacity", "1");
          $(title3).css("transition", "0.5s");
      }, 16000);
      setTimeout(function () {
          $(title3).css("opacity", "0");
      }, 21000);
      setTimeout(function () {
          $(title3).css("opacity", "1");
      }, 26500);
  });

}, 0);
```

or `setTimeout`

```
var timer;
!function loop()
{
  // Title
  var title1 = document.getElementById("slide-text-title-id");
  var title2 = document.getElementById("slide-text-title-id-2");
  var title3 = document.getElementById("slide-text-title-id-3");

  $(document).ready(function () {
      setTimeout(function () {
          $(title1).css("opacity", "1");
          $(title1).css("transition", "0.5s");
      }, 500);
      setTimeout(function () {
          $(title1).css("opacity", "0");
      }, 6000);
      setTimeout(function () {
          $(title1).css("opacity", "1");
      }, 20000);
  });

  $(document).ready(function () {
      setTimeout(function () {
          $(title2).css("opacity", "1");
          $(title2).css("transition", "0.5s");
      }, 9000);
      setTimeout(function () {
          $(title2).css("opacity", "0");
      }, 13500);
      setTimeout(function () {
          $(title2).css("opacity", "1");
      }, 20000);
  });

  $(document).ready(function () {
      setTimeout(function () {
          $(title3).css("opacity", "1");
          $(title3).css("transition", "0.5s");
      }, 16000);
      setTimeout(function () {
          $(title3).css("opacity", "0");
      }, 21000);
      setTimeout(function () {
          $(title3).css("opacity", "1");
      }, 26500);
  });
  timer = setTimeout(loop, 0);
}();
```

Comment: What is setTimer()? That is not a native method. And zero interval doesn't make any sense. An explanation into that is merited

Comment: I must have a stroke or something...supposed to be `setTimeout`, fixed. 0 interval = don't wait, execute immediately.